# Verifying HttpPostedFile ContentType

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm more used to programming in Java, but I find myself working in a C# project currently which involves the uploading of files.  In Java we have a package named Apache Tika which actually parses the contents of a file to determine the MimeType or ContentType of the file.  This is great for verification purposes to thwart uploads that clearly have a specific file extension but its contents say otherwise.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a class with a function in C# that does the same thing when dealing with the HttpPostedFile instance.  I'd like to use the InputStream property to parse the files' contents and return the MimeType/ContentType to see if it matches that which the file extension seems to indicate.

Please advise.

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase.ContentType` returns the MIME type of the posted content as a string.

Comment: So does HttpPostedFile.  The thing is, the ContentType is just based on header information from the client side.  I need to actually parse the file contents to determine the true nature of the file.